# Is there a better way to debug SQL?

Tags: sql, debugging

I have worked with SQL for several years now, primarily MySQL/PhpMyAdmin, but also Oracle/iSqlPlus and PL/SQL lately. I have programmed in PHP, Java, ActionScript and more. I realise SQL isn't an imperative programming language like the others - but why do the error messages seem so much less specific in SQL? In other environments I'm pointed straight to the root of the problem. More often that not, MySQL gives me errors like "error AROUND where u.id = ..." and prints the whole query. This is even more difficult with stored procedures, where debugging can be a complete nightmare.

Am I missing a magic tool/language/plugin/setting that gives better error reporting or are we stuck with this? I want a debugger or language which gives me the same amount of control that Eclipse gives me when setting breakpoints and stepping trough the code. Is this possible?

Comment: Sounds like a complaint more than a proper question.  Do you want a better debugger?  Do you want a better database?  What is it you want fixed?  Where's the code that doesn't work?

Comment: updated question to answer S.Lott

Comment: Maybe it would be good to rephrase your question like "Is there a way to get better (more detailed) error messages from SQL". Otherwise you may face closing as "not a question".

Comment: @lothar: added new paragraph, hoping to clarify

Comment: Edited to make the question more straightforward and removed the unnecessary complaining.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer lies in the fact that SQL is a set-based language with a few procedural things attached. Since the designers were thinking in set-based terms, they didn't think that the ordinary type of debugging that other languages have is important. However, I think some of this is changing. You can set breakpoints in SQL Server 2008. I haven't used it really as you must have SQL Server 2008 databases before it will work and most of ours are still SQL Server 2000. But it is available and it does allow you to step through things. You still are going to have problems when your select statement is 150 lines long and it knows that the syntax isn't right but it can't point out exactly where as it is all one command.

Personally when I am writing a long procedural SP, I build in a test mode that includes showing me the results of things I do, the values of key variables at specific points I'm interested in, and print staments that let me know what steps have been completed and then rolling the whole thing back when done. That way I can see what would have happened if it had run for real, but not have hurt any of the data in the database if I got it wrong. I find this very useful. It can vastly increase the size of your proc though. I have a template I use that has most of the structure I need set up in it, so it doesn't really take me too long to do. Especially since I never add an insert. update or delete to a proc without first testing the associated select to ensure I have the records I want.

Answer (score 4):

I think the explanation is that "regular" languages have much smaller individual statements than SQL, so that single-statement granularity points to a much smaller part of the code in them than in SQL.  A single SQL statement can be a page or more in length; in other languages it's usually a single line.

I don't think that makes it impossible for debuggers / IDEs to more precisely identify errors, but I suspect it makes it harder.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with your complaint.

Building a good logging framework and overusing it in your sprocs is what works best for me.

Before and after every transaction or important piece of logic, I write out the sproc name, step timestamp and a rowcount (if relevant) to my log table.  I find that when I have done this, I can usually narrow down the problem spot within a few minutes.

Add a debug parameter to the sproc (default to "N") and pass it through to any other sprocs that it calls so that you can easily turn logging on or off.

Answer (score 1):

As for breakpoints and stepping through code, you can do this with MS SQL Server (in my opinion, it's easier on 2005+ than with 2000).

For the simple cases, early development debugging, the sometimes cryptic messages are usually good enough to get the error resolved -- syntax error, can't do X with Y.  If I'm in a tough sproc, I'll revert to "printf debugging" on the sproc text because it's quick and easy.  After a while with your database of choice, the simple issues become old hat and you just take them in stride.

However, once the code is released, the complexity of the issues is way too high.  I consider myself lucky if I can reproduce them.  Also, the places where the developer in me would want a debugger the DBA in me says "no way you're putting a debugger there."

Answer (score 0):

I do use the following tactics.

During writing of the stored procedure have a @procStep var
each time a new logical step is executed 
set @procStep = "What the ... is happening here " ;

the rest is [here](http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2009/06/debugging-procedure-with-table-for-sql.html)